# Animating a UITextview in a UIToolbar issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uiviewanimation, uitoolbar

I am trying to animate a UITextView to expand the to the width of its containing UIToolbar.
But it animates weird, jumping around.

[image]

Can anyone help me make understand why my textbox jumps around?

```
#define ANIMATION_DURATION 0.5
#define ANIMATION_DELAY    0.03
    @interface WebViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>{
        CGRect URLBAR_DEFAULT;
    }

    -(void)viewDidLoad{
    self.txtURLBar = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        self.txtURLBar.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30);
        self.txtURLBar.delegate = self;
        self.txtURLBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        self.txtURLBar.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;


        URLBAR_DEFAULT = self.txtURLBar.frame; //KEEP A REFRENCE TO THE ORIGINAL SIZE
    }


//START EDITING EXPAND TO FULL WIDTH
  - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION delay:ANIMATION_DELAY options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
            [_txtURLBar setFrame:CGRectMake(3, URLBAR_DEFAULT.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width - 10, URLBAR_DEFAULT.size.height)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

    }

//END EDITING SHRINK BACK TO SMALL SIZE
    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION delay:ANIMATION_DELAY options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            [_txtURLBar setFrame:CGRectMake(URLBAR_DEFAULT.origin.x, URLBAR_DEFAULT.origin.y, URLBAR_DEFAULT.size.width, URLBAR_DEFAULT.size.height)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to the frame being set in textFieldDidBeginEditing, textFieldDidEndEditing is different. I've done the small POC with same code of yours as below. It's working fine.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *resizeableTextField;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//START EDITING EXPAND TO FULL WIDTH
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.03 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

        self.resizeableTextField.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.resizeableTextField.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.resizeableTextField.frame), self.resizeableTextField.frame.size.width + 40, CGRectGetHeight(self.resizeableTextField.frame));
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

}

//END EDITING SHRINK BACK TO SMALL SIZE
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.03 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        self.resizeableTextField.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.resizeableTextField.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.resizeableTextField.frame), self.resizeableTextField.frame.size.width - 40, CGRectGetHeight(self.resizeableTextField.frame));
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}

@end
```